# Is it possible to bind an asp:GridView to a List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I've got a GridView :

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdRestitutions" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
 <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="JobNumber" HeaderText="Job" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ContainerType" HeaderText="Type" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ReleaseDate" HeaderText="Date" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Commodity" HeaderText="Commodity" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="GrossWeight" HeaderText="Weight" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="SpecialInstructions" HeaderText="Special Instructions" />
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

That I'm trying to set the DataSource to be a `List<Restitution>()` where `Restitution` is a public structure consisting only of public members; i.e.:

```
public struct Restitution
{
    public int ContainerReleasesId;
    public int ContainerId;
    public System.DateTime ReleaseDate;
    public int DepotId;
    public string DepotName;
    public string JobNumber;
    public string BillOfLadingNumber;
    public string BookingType;
    public string Commodity;
    public string SpecialInstructions;
    public int GrossWeight;
    public bool Confirmed;
    public bool RecievedFlag;
    public bool ReleaseSource;
    public int ContainerTypeId;
    public string InOut;
    public string ContainerTypeDescription;
}
```

The data binding looks fairly innocuous, too:

```
grdRestitutions.DataSource = restitutions;
grdRestitutions.DataBind();
```

However, an exception is thrown on the `DataBind()` statement with the less than helpful message of:

> "A field or property with the name 'JobNumber' was not found on the selected data source."

I don't understand why this isn't working; whilst most examples and use cases seem to use `DataSet`s it does appear that it should support objects implementing `IEnumerable`. Is there anything special I have to do to allow it to work?

Comment: Your code does look correct to me. Are you sure your binding with the correct data source and its not null or anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convert all public fields for public properties and it should work.

```
public struct ContainerRelease
{
    public int ContainerReleasesId {get; set;} 
    public int ContainerId {get; set;} 
    public System.DateTime ReleaseDate  {get; set;} 
    ...
}
```

Comment: But the exception says "A field or property"

Comment: @Magnus Ah, true! I have always used properties. Can you give properties a shot? if it doesn't work, i'll delete my answer.

Comment: @Magnus seems like you fell for the "trust what the exception says" trick as well as me. Turns out that it doesn't *appear* to support data binding from members (even public ones), only properties...

Comment: In VB.NET it works: `public structure ContainerRelease
    public property ContainerReleasesId as integer
    public property ContainerId as integer
    public ReleaseDate as System.DateTime
    ...
end structure

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdRestitutions" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
 <Columns>
  <asp:templatefield headertext="Job">
    <itemtemplate>
          <asp:label id="JobNumberLabel"
            Text="<%# ((Restitution)Container.DataItem).JobNumber %>" 
            runat="server"/> 
    </itemtemplate>
  </asp:templatefield>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This code casts each bound row to a `Restitution` object, then accesses the `JobNumber` field directly. If this works, you can bind the other fields similarly. If it *doesn't* work, the error should lead you to the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to bind the list in this case. The thing is you need to do something more like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdRestitutions" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
 <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="DataItem.JobNumber" HeaderText="Job" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="DataItem.ContainerType" HeaderText="Type" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="DataItem.ReleaseDate" HeaderText="Date" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="DataItem.Commodity" HeaderText="Commodity" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="DataItem.GrossWeight" HeaderText="Weight" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="DataItem.SpecialInstructions" HeaderText="Special Instructions" />
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If that doesn't work you could possibly try using TemplateColumns like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdRestitutions" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job" >
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Job") %>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Not tested but should give you someplace to go...